# Compare each element of 1st list to all elements of second list to find a match

Tags: vba

I have two lists that I'm trying to compare with each other to find out what the other does not have.

I need to exclude the duplicates and just find out if the first list has all the items of the second. If it doesn't than I want to find out which of the items of the second list that the first does not have.

here's what I've tried

```
Sub CompareLists()

    first = Worksheets("firstworksheet").Range("datalist1").Value2
  
    second = Worksheets("secondworksheet").Range("datalist2").Value2

    
    For i = LBound(first) To UBound(first)
        For j = LBound(second) To UBound(second)
            toCompare1 = LCase(Trim(first(i, 1)))
            toCompare2 = LCase(Trim(second(j, 1)))
            If toCompare1 = toCompare2 Then
                Debug.Print toCompare1 & " -- " & toCompare2
                exit for
            Else
                Debug.Print toCompare1 & " not " & toCompare2
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: And your issue is...? Sidenote: There's no `end for`, I believe you are looking for `Exit For`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will fix and clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to declare all variables (Putting `Option Explicit` at the top of the module will help you enforce this).

```
Private Sub CompareLists()

    Dim first As Variant
    Dim second As Variant
    
    Dim itemMissing As Object
        
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    first = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("firstworksheet").Range("datalist1").Value)
    second = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("secondworksheet").Range("datalist2").Value)
                                        
    Set itemMissing = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For j = LBound(second) To UBound(second)
        If IsError(Application.Match(second(j), first, 0)) Then 'If Match returns Error = not found
            itemMissing(second(j)) = True
        End If
    Next j
    
    If itemMissing.Count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "first has all items of second!"
    Else
        Debug.Print "first do not have these values in second:" & vbNewLine & Join(itemMissing.Keys, ", ")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I found doing this really challenging although I've done it in python already

Comment: Is there a way to trim them? As in removing empty spaces in the beginning or end of both list item being compared

Comment: I suppose you can do a for loop for `first` and `second` and apply the trim function? Right after you assigned `first` and `second`.